# How to get json data from rails to react js?

Tags: reactjs

I have tried using ajax call to get data from rails to react but the state was not updating. When I tried to call state it's giving me an error that it is undefined. I have referred other questions in stack overflow but couldn't solve my problem. Here is my my ajax request.

```js
fetchData: function(){
      $.ajax({
        url: '/orders',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(result) {
          this.setState({orders: result});
        }.bind(this),
        error: function(xhr, status, err) {
          console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
        }.bind(this)
      });
    }
```

[Click this link to view the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kWRbw.png)

```
<p><button  onClick={this.fetchData}>Filter</button></p>
            <div>
              {
                Object.keys(this.state.orders).map(function(key){
                  return <div key={ key }>{this.state.orders[key]}</div>
                }, this)
              }
            </div>
```

Comment: Please provide some more details about your react components and error which you are getting

Comment: undefined error may mean null or incorrect json return

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to render the order object as a string. React doesn't like that. Try only rendering a value, not the whole `order` object, for example like this:

```js
class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { orders: {
      first: { id: 311, name: 'Eric' },
      second: { id: 420, name: 'Andre' },
    }};
  }
  render() {
    return(
      <div>
      {
        Object.keys(this.state.orders).map(function(key){
          return <div key={ key }>{this.state.orders[key].id}</div>
        }, this)
      }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById('View'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id='View'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error says that you are trying to render something that is an object, which is not possible. The problem can be found here:

```
return <div key={ key }>{this.state.orders[key]}</div>
```

If you want to render this, then `this.state.orders[key]` should be either a JSX element or a value (a string for example), and it doesn't seem to be the case. I don't know what do you assign to `orders` with `this.setState({orders: result});`. If you show us the value of `result` we might be able to help more, but right now the problem is that `this.state.orders[key]` is an object.